# Can we use two "use: href" properties in the same SVG?

Tags: html, svg

Can you use more than one "USE" method inside an SVG tag?

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <use href="#eye-fill" />
</svg>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <use href="#eye-slash-fill" />
</svg>
```

to,

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <use href="#eye-fill" />
    <use href="#eye-slash-fill" style="display: none" /> <!-- Toggle display -->
</svg>
```

Comment: have you try :) ?

Comment: Yes it works. But maybe it's wrong to use with HTML standards or if there is any obstacle, it doesn't matter if it works :)

Comment: As you can see multiple use is acept - [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use)

Comment: @SimoneRossaini Thank you for this answer. I'll read more for the link :) Can you answer this question? I'll also tick it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in MDN web docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use) `use` can be use multiple time.

Example from MDN:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 30 10" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle id="myCircle" cx="5" cy="5" r="4" stroke="blue"/>
  <use href="#myCircle" x="10" fill="blue"/>
  <use href="#myCircle" x="20" fill="white" stroke="red"/>
  <!--
stroke="red" will be ignored here, as stroke was already set on myCircle. 
Most attributes (except for x, y, width, height and (xlink:)href)
do not override those set in the ancestor.
That's why the circles have different x positions, but the same stroke value.
  -->
</svg>
```